# how to set LinearProgressIndicator height in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have used CircularProgressIndicator to show the progress, I used strokeWidth in CircularProgressIndicator to make it thin but now i have to use LinearProgressIndicator and as i can see **there is nothing like strokeWidth for LinearProgressIndicator**.

What should i do?

```
 new IconButton(
               icon: 
                _isLoading
                    ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 1,),)
                    : 
                    Icon(Icons.check,),
 ),
```

Right now i am using LinearProgressIndicator like below but it is very thick

```
new IconButton(
                   icon: 
                    _isLoading
                        ? Center(child: LinearProgressIndicator(),)
                        : 
                        Icon(Icons.check,),
     ),
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a [`minHeight`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/LinearProgressIndicator/minHeight.html) property in [`LinearProgressIndicator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/LinearProgressIndicator-class.html)

> `minHeight` → `double`
> The minimum height of the line used to draw the indicator.
> `final`
>
> This defaults to `4dp`.

If you also want to control it's `width` and `height`, wrap it using a `Container` or `SizedBox` and use `width` property as you want.

Ex:

```
SizedBox(
  width: 100,
  child: LinearProgressIndicator(minHeight: 3),
),
```

Comment: minHeight is not working , getting error like -> The named parameter 'minHeight' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'minHeight'.

Comment: @IshwarChandraTiwari Try this dartpad demo: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/512da0b44df9be65fcfb7b4f55b09bbf